# How to focus on browser tab using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, tabs

In my application, I want to move focus from my current browser tab to another tab (which is already open in same browser), so please help how can I achieve this.

Comment: If it's a tab opened by your app, then look into `window.open`. if it's an arbitrary tab (e.g. the 1st tab or any gmail tab), then that's not possible for security/privacy reasons.

Comment: So how did you open the other tab?